# How can I redraw this circuit where I can apply Kirchoff's Voltage and Current Law to get correct Voltage at V?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image]

I thought I can draw the -5 V as a source but it did not turn out to be right, unfortunately.

Comment: I answered your question, but it might be helpful to point you to the [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) exchange.

Comment: What is the correct voltage at V? It seems like we are missing some information here...

Comment: The schematic shows V connected directly to +2 V. Why do you think you need any analysis at all to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to redraw this circuit or perform any calculations. The +2 V and v are on the same node. Everything on the same node has the same voltage, so v = 2 V.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there's nothing connecting the *+1V* node to anything else on the circuit, so we can delete it. There's nothing connected to the *V* node, which means we can eliminate that leg. There's nothing connecting the pins (the unfilled circles) to anything, so the leg between the *+2V* node and the filled circle is a short (it's all the same voltage).

So basically, you've got a *+2V* node up top, a *2 k$\Omega$* resistor in the middle, and a *5V* node on the bottom. Your *V* node is connected just above the resistor.

If you want, you can write in a *5V* power source (negative end at the *-5V* node, positive end at a ground symbol you add in), and a *2V* power source (positive end at the *+2V* node, negative end at the ground symbol you just added). This will make it look like your textbooks, but isn't required.

Alternately, you can just add a *7V* power source with the positive end at the *+2V* node and the negative end at the *-5V* node. It's mathematically the same. At that point you can add 5V to every node while you do the math (so your ground is at 0V instead of -5V), then subtract 5V from all the nodes when you're done. But again, it's not required, and the math will work regardless.

Of course, if you connect the four pins to other components, or connect something to the *V* node, the schematic gets more tricky and you have to use node analysis which you'll probably learn soon if you haven't already started.